How to write contents of a tar file to disk
For the below posted code, connectForTar is the method that receives .tar contents. The method writeForPath is used to write the .tar contents to a .tar file.
At run time, there is a file .tar written to the disk but when I try to unzip it, i receive some kind of message that indicates it is not a valid archive.
I am sure that what i am receiving in connectForTar method is a valid .tar file, because the latter method receives response from sentinelhub and i confirmed that the request i am sending and the response i am receiving are valid.
please let me know how to solve this issue.
connectForTar
connectForTar(options, body, onResult) {
    const resCallback = (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Code:",response.statusCode);
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Msg:",response.statusMessage);
            onResult(response.statusCode, null);
            response.resume();
            return;
        }
        
        let data = [];
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
            console.info({msg:infoTag +' response ended',contents:buffer})
            onResult(response.statusCode, buffer);
        });

        }
    const req = https.request(options, resCallback);
    req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.:", err);
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.stack:", err.stack);
    });
    req.end();
}

writeForPath:
static writeForPath(fileName, outputPath, contents, ext='.tiff') {
    let updatedExt = '';
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
     
        if (!fs.existsSync(outputPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(outputPath, {recursive:true});
        }
        const fullPath = outputPath + fileName + updatedExt;
        fs.writeFile(fullPath, contents,{flag:'w'},(error)=> {
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error({msg:errorTag + "error occured while writing data to file", err:error}));
                throw new Error({msg:errorTag + "error occured while writing data to file", err:error.message});
            }
            resolve({msg:infoTag + "successfully saved the data to file", fullPath:fullPath, fileName: fileName + updatedExt});
        });
    });
}

how methods and code are related
await Promise.all([
    sentinelHubProcessAPI.requestNDVIsGeoTIFFForTS1(resp.access_token,geojson,satelliteMissionType,endpoint, operand1StartDay,operand1StartMonth,operand1StartYear,operand1EndDay,operand1EndMonth,operand1EndYear, (resultCode, contents) => {
    }),
    .....
    .....
])

requestNDVIsGeoTIFFForTS1(fetchedToken,coordsInEPSG3857,satMissionType,endpoint, sDay,sMonth,sYear,eDay,eMonth,eYear, onResult) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        switch(endpoint) {
            case SentinelhubMissionsEndpoints.CONST_SENTINELHUB_ENDPOINT_IS_SEVICES.description:
                this.#connOptsForTS1 = this.#processHTTPAPIForTS1.createOptionsForEndpointIsServices('POST', SentinelHubRequestHeader.getRequestHeaderMultipartFormData(fetchedToken));
                break;
            case SentinelhubMissionsEndpoints.CONST_SENTINELHUB_ENDPOINT_IS_CREODIAS.description:
                this.#connOptsForTS1 = this.#processHTTPAPIForTS1.createOptionsForEndpointIsCreodias('POST', SentinelHubRequestHeader.getRequestHeaderMultipartFormData(fetchedToken));
                break;
            case SentinelhubMissionsEndpoints.CONST_SENTINELHUB_ENDPOINT_IS_CODEDE.description:
                this.#connOptsForTS1 = this.#processHTTPAPIForTS1.createOptionsForEndpointIsCodeDE('POST', SentinelHubRequestHeader.getRequestHeaderMultipartFormData(fetchedToken));
                break;
            case SentinelhubMissionsEndpoints.CONST_SENTINELHUB_ENDPOINT_IS_USWEST2.description:
                this.#connOptsForTS1 = this.#processHTTPAPIForTS1.createOptionsForEndpointIsUSWEST2('POST', SentinelHubRequestHeader.getRequestHeaderMultipartFormData(fetchedToken));
                break;
            default:
                this.#msg = ({msg:errorTag + 'Unhandeled condition. where:', endpoint:endpoint});
                console.log(this.#msg);
                throw new Error(this.#msg);
        };
        
        await this.#processHTTPAPIForTS1.connectForTar(this.#connOptsForTS1,SentinelhubJSONRequest.jsonRequestNDVIAsTimeSeriesInGeoTIFFForParameters(satMissionType,coordsInEPSG3857,sDay,sMonth,sYear,eDay,eMonth,eYear), (resultCode, contents) => {
            if (resultCode < 200 || resultCode > 299) {
                reject({msg:errorTag + 'requestNDVIsGeoTIFFForTS1() failed. connectForTIFF() returns a rejected promise', resultCode:resultCode, contents: contents});
                onResult(resultCode, contents);
            } else {
                resolve({msg:infoTag + 'requestNDVIsGeoTIFFForTS1() succeeded. connectForTIFF() returns a resolved promise', resultCode:resultCode, contents: contents});
                onResult(resultCode, contents);
            }
        });
    });
}

connectForTar(options, body, onResult) {
    const resCallback = (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Code:",response.statusCode);
            console.error(errorTag,"Did not get an OK from the server. Msg:",response.statusMessage);
            onResult(response.statusCode, null);
            response.resume();
            return;
        }
        
        let data = [];
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk);
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
            const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
            console.info({msg:infoTag +' response ended',contents:buffer})
            onResult(response.statusCode, buffer);
        });
    }
    
    const req = https.request(options, resCallback);
    req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.:", err);
        console.error(errorTag + "problem with request.e.stack:", err.stack);
    });
    req.end();
}


'i receive some kind of message that indicates it is not a valid archive.' is of no use to anyone in order to give assistance, edit your post with actual details - ie what the actual error message is, also if there is a file written, use a command line tool (tar) to inspect the file and see what happens.

How are connectForTar() and writeForPath() related? Nothing in either of these functions is specific to tar files. They just read and write files.

@Barmar morning, sorry for the belated reply. however, i posted a new section contains an answer to your question. would you please tell me whether i correctly receive the .tar contents?

connectForTar() is not declared async and doesn't return a Promise. So it doesn't make much sense to await it.

I still don't see a call to writeForPath() anywhere.
